# Filtering nested key value pair based on a specific value

Tags: javascript, angular, key-value

I am doing key value pair mapping for the first time and not been able to approach. I have a key value pair like :

```
trips= {
    date1: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Delhi", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01001"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 2, 
        "Place": "Bangalore", 
        "Number": "002",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh2", "number": "AN01002"}
      },
      { 
        "id": 3, 
        "Place": "Pune", 
        "Number": "003",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh3", "number": "AN01003"}
      } 
    ],
    date2: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Lucknow", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01002"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 3, 
        "Place": "Pune", 
        "Number": "003",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh3", "number": "AN01003"}
      } 
    ],
    date3: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Delhi", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01001"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 2, 
        "Place": "Bangalore", 
        "Number": "002",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh2", "number": "AN01002"}
      }
   ]
}

for (date in trips) {
  var places = trips[date]
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; ++i) {
    var place = places[i]
    console.log('place', place)
    console.log('Vehicle', place.Vehicle)
  }
}
```

Inside dates the data are stored in form of array which have key value pair. I need to print all the dates which have vehicle id as "veh2" inside it. I am trying to loop through the data. but not finding the right way after a certain point where the array starts.

I have been able to loop through one nested key value pair

```
for (key in trips){
    var value= trips[key]
    for (k in value)
        {
            //further nested logic
        }

}
```

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: I suggest using pandas dataframes for handling such data

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh can't it be done any other way?

Comment: It can be, of course! But it's much easier this way

Comment: @UDGogs There are alot of ways. You have to give a valid data and expected output

Comment: @UDGogs You may want to add valid data, the structure you added doesn't validate

Comment: @Ignacio corrected it

Comment: @NinaScholz check out the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get all the dates that contain your Vehicle with id === veh2:

```
const t = Object.entries(trips);
const res = t.filter((dates) => {
  return dates[1].some((d, e) => {
    return d.Vehicle.id == 'veh2'; 
  });
});
console.log(res);
```

This would return arrays for date1 and date3 (which contain veh2)

EDIT (version2):

This returns the dates much cleaner:

```
let res = [];
for(let i in trips) {
  const found = trips[i].filter((dates) => dates.Vehicle.id == 'veh2');
  found.length && res.push(trips[i]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your major problem is the wrong structured data as @Nina Scholz already mentioned, when having this corrected it is pretty easy to run through everything:

```js
trips= {
    date1: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Delhi", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01001"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 2, 
        "Place": "Bangalore", 
        "Number": "002",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh2", "number": "AN01002"}
      },
      { 
        "id": 3, 
        "Place": "Pune", 
        "Number": "003",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh3", "number": "AN01003"}
      } 
    ],
    date2: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Lucknow", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01002"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 3, 
        "Place": "Pune", 
        "Number": "003",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh3", "number": "AN01003"}
      } 
    ],
    date3: [ 
      {
        "id": 1, 
        "Place": "Delhi", 
        "Number": "001",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh1", "number": "AN01001"} 
      },
      { 
        "id": 2, 
        "Place": "Bangalore", 
        "Number": "002",
        "Vehicle": {"id":"veh2", "number": "AN01002"}
      }
   ]
}

for (date in trips) {
  var places = trips[date]
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; ++i) {
    var place = places[i]
    console.log('place', place)
    console.log('Vehicle', place.Vehicle)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With poper formatted objects and arrays, you could filter single places where the id matches.

```js
var trips = { date1: [{ id: 1, Place: "Delhi", Number: "001", Vehicle: { id: "veh1", number: "AN01001" } }, { id: 2, Place: "Bangalore", Number: "002", Vehicle: { id: "veh2", number: "AN01002" } }, { id: 3, Place: "Pune", Number: "003", Vehicle: { id: "veh3", number: "AN01003" } }], date2: [{ id: 1, Place: "Lucknow", Number: "001", Vehicle: { id: "veh1", number: "AN01002" } }, { id: 3, Place: "Pune", Number: "003", Vehicle: { id: "veh3", number: "AN01003" } }], date3: [{ id: 1, Place: "Delhi", Number: "001", Vehicle: { id: "veh1", number: "AN01001" } }, { id: 2, Place: "Bangalore", Number: "002", Vehicle: { id: "veh2", number: "AN01002" } }] },
    id = "veh2",
    result = Object.keys(trips).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r.concat(trips[k].filter(function (place) {
            return place.Vehicle.id === id;
        }));
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code.

```js
trips = {
    date1: [{
            "id": 1,
            "Place": "Delhi",
            "Number": "001",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh1",
                "number": "AN01001"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Place": "Bangalore",
            "Number": "002",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh2",
                "number": "AN01002"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Place": "Pune",
            "Number": "003",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh3",
                "number": "AN01003"
            }
        }
    ],
    date2: [{
            "id": 1,
            "Place": "Lucknow",
            "Number": "001",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh1",
                "number": "AN01002"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Place": "Pune",
            "Number": "003",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh3",
                "number": "AN01003"
            }
        }
    ],
    date3: [{
            "id": 1,
            "Place": "Delhi",
            "Number": "001",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh1",
                "number": "AN01001"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Place": "Bangalore",
            "Number": "002",
            "Vehicle": {
                "id": "veh2",
                "number": "AN01002"
            }
        }
    ]
};


var results = [];

for (var date in trips) {
    for (var index = 0; index < trips[date].length; index++) {
        var data = trips[date][index];
        var vehicle = data.Vehicle;

        if (vehicle.number == 'AN01002') {
            results.push(data);
        }
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use `foreach` like this :

```
trips.foreach((item) =>{
//here item is date1, date2
// then you can do 
item.id = 2; // every stuff you want !!!
```

});